# How to disable clicking on BaseAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, baseadapter

I have a BaseAdapter which shows an array of values. If the array is empty, I want to disable the BaseAdapter (so you can't click it). Is there any way to do so? Note that I want to do this dynamically. Overriding isEnabled() is not viable.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share some code? Click won't work if you don't set converView.setOnclickListener. What's your case? Please edit your question and make it clearer.

Comment: Yes if you haven't set onClickListener nothing will happen even on clicking ,so that should not be a problem

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have "class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter" which overrides getCount(), getItem(int position), getItemId(int position), getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). I think we might not be on the same page here. My problem is that if the adapter has an empty list, the adapter is still clickable. It shows an animation where its color goes to orange and back to gray on click (it doesn't pop up the listview). What I want is to completely gray the adapter out. It should have the same behavior as when I disable a button by Button.setEnabled(false).